# Scala multi-module project?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

- I have `Java` background and thinking of learning `Scala`.
- One of this things that I like about using `Maven` is that I can make a project as multi-maven module. Example?

> ```
> Project/pom.xml
>        /persistence/pom.xml
>        /business/pom.xml
>        /services/pom.xml
> ```

The nice thing about it is that each of these modules can have their own dependencies and they can be tested independently, rather than running one monolith application.

How do we achieve something similar in `Scala`, `sbt` or its ecosystem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely do it. It's called [SBT Multi-Project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html). You can define one master project and multiple child projects with something like this (from the docs link above):

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object HelloBuild extends Build {
    lazy val root = Project(id = "hello",
                            base = file(".")) aggregate(foo, bar)

    lazy val foo = Project(id = "hello-foo",
                           base = file("foo"))

    lazy val bar = Project(id = "hello-bar",
                           base = file("bar"))
}
```

Each project can be built separately, you can also package each into a separate JAR, or combine them all into a single master JAR. Each project can define it's own dependencies, but they can also be shared if needed. Basically you have full control. Take a look at my project build file [here](https://github.com/izmailoff/Spray_Mongo_REST_service/blob/master/project/Build.scala) for example.

Comment: This uses obsolete syntax for an old version of SBT. Current macro-based definitions looks differently and more cleanly. See [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html).

Comment: The one master, two child is not the only configuration right ? Is it also possible to have two master, one common child right ?

Comment: @jhegedus yes true. The aggregate root project is mostly to make it easy to compile everything in one shot (by default). You can always switch to separate projects and build only them

Comment: Thanks for clarification.