# Scala/Java Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I need help on developing enterprise scale Java/Scala applications with multiple components/modules involving multiple JARS.

The purpose is, currently the exsisted code is developed as a single component with a single JAR, basically I need some guidance on how to break-up this huge component into multiple Spark/Scala modules with its own JAR, also all the common util functions need to be in the common component like CORE.

The idea behind this refactoring is to call the **individual components in parallel depending on the use case and not call each module in sequence**.

Are there any tools to make this process (at least partially) automatic or do we have any plug-ins built in in the IntelliJ IDE?

Suggestions or pointers are welcome.

Comment: You can use a plugin based approach, where the plugins are runned by the main core

Comment: you can use multi module project in gradle(https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) or maven(https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) or SBT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no tool which does this..
But you can use Maven Archetype (command line maven option) to generate a multi module project (***aggregator-style***).

I'm giving an example of maven [multi module project](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-multi-module-project.html).
I think there will be same way you can do it for Gradle or other tools
adjust your code

#### Create an archetype from a multi-module project

Creating an archetype for a multi-module project is as simple as creating one for a single-module project.

Just move to the root directory of a multi-module project and call `mvn archetype:create-from-project`. In the archetype used as an example, some files need to be non filtered. This is achieved by giving the archetype plugin some values in the `archetype.filteredExtensions` property.

```
$ mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.filteredExtensions=java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order:
[INFO]   archetype
[INFO]   archetype :: business domain model
[INFO]   archetype :: business services
[INFO]   archetype :: persistence layer
[INFO]   archetype :: infrastructure
[INFO]   archetype :: remoting
[INFO]   archetype :: web services
[INFO]   archetype :: web application
[INFO]   archetype :: enterprise application
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype
[INFO]    task-segment: [archetype:create-from-project] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing archetype:create-from-project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: business domain model
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: business services
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: persistence layer
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: infrastructure
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: remoting
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: web services
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: web application
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [gwt:eclipse {execution: default}]
[INFO] Unpack native libraries required to run hosted browser
[INFO] [gwt:generateAsync {execution: default}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building archetype :: enterprise application
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[INFO] [archetype:create-from-project]
[INFO] Setting default groupId: com.capgemini.archetype
[INFO] Setting default artifactId: archetype
[INFO] Setting default version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Setting default package: com.capgemini
[INFO] Archetype created in target/generated-sources/archetype
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 15 19:11:17 CEST 2008
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/36M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also look at

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159537/647053
- https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/scala-multimodule-sample-project/blob/master/pom.xml